# unable to load list of options under the button using angular material menu

Tags: html, css, angular-material2

I am using angular  material design and when i clicked on the menu button, the options are displaying on top of the button .

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>
```

[image]

How to display options below the button like in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `overlapTrigger` property of the `mat-menu` to `false` in order to show the menu items below the trigger. Please take a look at [this stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bbqxyajorby).

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" overlapTrigger="false">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```